# jQuery: Set display:none if an element has no children

Tags: jquery, children

So I have a `aside` element that contains some div. The div are generated with PHP, and sometimes the aside has no div children.

What I want is to hide this aside parent when it doesnt have any div children.

So far i've tried different solutions has

```
if($('aside').length)
    {
        if($('aside').find('*').length == 0)
        {
            $('aside').hide();
        }
    }
```

obv not working.

the php looks like that

```
<aside>
    <div class="children1"></div>
    <div class="children2"></div>
</aside>
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use this to hide all `aside` elements without children :

```
$('aside').filter(function(){ return !$(this).children().length }).hide()
```

[Demonstration](http://jsbin.com/yoviw/3/edit)

Note that it's usually easy to test in PHP if you have elements to write and in the opposite case, simply not write the `aside` element. Instead of sending HTML and erase it client side, I'd rather not send it.

Answer (score 1):

The following will hide all aside tags that don't contain anything at all.

```
$('aside:empty').hide();
```

However it doesn't work if it contains whitespace, or empty child nodes

After a lot of fiddling around I figured out that if you want to do this client-side then your best option is to iterate over all the asides and determine which ones don't contain anything meaningful.  The following code seems to do the job adequately.

```
$('aside').each (function (index, elem) {
    elem = $(elem);
    if ('' == elem.text ().trim ()) {
        elem.hide ();
    }
});
```

[JSFiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/fB48q/).

However, it's probably better to just not include the  at all in the markup when generating it server side if there's nothing to go in it.  It'll reduce the amount of data you need to send (slightly) and be rendered correctly regardless of whether the user has javascript enabled.

Comment: Even one space between the tags would render it as not empty. Otherwise it's a decent solution.

Comment: doesn't work for me :(    
the pseudo element empty works on all browsers ? IE ?

Comment: Okay, bit of playing with jsfiddle.  It will work for an empty aside, but if it contains anything at all (including white space or nothing but empty child nodes) it doesn't. Looking for a better solution.

Answer (score 0):

```
if($('aside').children(":first").length == 0)
{
     $('aside').hide();
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Pay attention to the running time of the script

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    if ( !$('aside').children().length )
        $('aside').hide();
};
```

Additionally you shouldn't refer to the element by its TagType ('aside'). Use identifiers or classes.

Comment: That will hide all aside elements if any of them are empty.

Comment: There's so little in your answer other than the code sample that it's pretty much useless.